# Clipping pixels under a polygon

Tags: c#, image, graphics

I am attempting to retrieve the pixels under a polygon; however, I seem to be unable to correctly get all the pixels accurately. Below is the code I have:

```
private void DrawPolygon()
{
    PointF[] pts = new PointF[]{new PointF(5.196057f, 4.13434839f), new PointF(5.528517f, 4.621298f), new PointF(7.073008f, 6.5661006f), new  PointF(5.28491259f, 9.206118f), new PointF(4.80768776f, 6.595068f), new PointF(5.196057f, 4.13434839f)};
    GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath(FillMode.Alternate);
    gp.AddPolygon(pts);
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.FromFile("...");
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
    g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;
    using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.White))
    {
        g.FillPath(b, gp);
    }

    bmp.Save("...");
}
```

In the image below (left) you can see that several pixels under the polygon are excluded. Image on the right was the original with all pixels having a value. I feel that I am missing a setting in the 'Graphics', but I cannot figure out what.

[image]

Comment: Looks like only those pixels which are inside with 50+% get filled. Seems right to me. You could add a DrawPath to hit the border pixels with a pen.. - Also: Please try to post only real code! (The snippet is not complete and doesn't even compile)

Comment: Sorry, I was only trying to post relevant code. A draw path will add a few more pixels, but will still miss some of the slivers

Comment: That would depend on the pen's properties; but then you might fill in more that you want..

Comment: It's true, I have tried with different widths. It will bring me closer to the correct solution, but it will not get the all the pixels (or it get's pixels that are not covered by the polygon). Are you saying that it is not possible to what I want with graphics?

Comment: Not sure. Usually a rounding problem (which is what this seems to me) is solved by changing the data; often by 'adding 1/2'. If you add 1/2 pixel (from inside) the result should be right. But to do that one would need to have knowledge on the polygons..

Comment: I've changed and added a few lines to make the code compile correctly: obviously replace the "..." with a file. I have already added the 'PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half' which would adjust the 1/2 pixel.

Comment: What I meant was to make the polygon __larger__ by 1/2 pixel. The PixelOffsetMode.Half doesn't do that; usually it would be wrong; in fact most cases would consider the result you have to be the only correct one!